# Not able to insert different values of struct into Map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I use Node to hold (x, y) of coordinator and try to insert 4 nodes into map. The following code only print 2 nodes, why?

```
{0,0}, 0
{1,2}, 3
```

If i change the code of overload operator '<' with

```
bool operator<(const Node &ob) const
{
    return x < ob.x or y < ob.y;
}
```

It prints all 4 nodes. My understanding the operator< only impact the ordering of keys.

### code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct Node
{
    T1 x;
    T2 y;

    Node(T1 x, T2 y): x(x), y(y) {}

    bool operator<(const Node &ob) const
    {
        return x < ob.x and y < ob.y;
    }
    
    bool operator==(const Node &ob) const
    {
        return x == ob.x and y == ob.y;
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    std::map<Node<int, int>, int> map =
    {
        {{0, 0}, 0},
        {{0, 1}, 1},
        {{1, 0}, 2},
        {{1, 2}, 3}
    };

    for (const auto &entry: map)
    {
        auto key = entry.first;
        std::cout << "{" << key.x << "," << key.y << "}, " << entry.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::map requries that `operator<` generates a _"strict weak ordering"_ relationship yours does not.  A simple fix is to replace the contents of `operator<` with `return std::tie(x, y) < std:;tie(ob.x, ob.y);`  `std::map` also synthesizes the equality test from `!operator<(a, b) && !operator<(b, a).` see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: @RichardCritten wouldn't this do the same thing his current overload is doing?

Comment: @smac89 `std::tie` does `return x < ob.x || (x == ob.x && y < ob.y);`  ie a lexicographical compare. see (3) here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp

Comment: I think the better question is: "Where did my content go?" If the map is simply ignoring certain entries, that is an entirely different problem, but maybe the stuff that wasn't printed just never made it into the map. You should investigate this

Comment: @smac89 The missing entries probably never made it into the map in the first place because the faulty comparator made the map believe that some of these entries were duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map` considers two element to be equal if for two keys `a` and `b`, the comparator (in your case, the default, `std::less`) fulfils

```
!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)
```

Let's check your case:

First you insert the key `Node<int, int>(0, 0)`, then the key `Node<int, int>(0, 1)`. For these elements (and your `operator<`) the following holds:

```
!std::less(Node<int, int>(0, 0), Node<int, int>(0, 1))
&& !std::less(Node<int, int>(0, 0), Node<int, int>(0, 1)) 
=>
!(Node<int, int>(0, 0) < Node<int, int>(0, 1))
&& !(Node<int, int>(0, 1) < Node<int, int>(0, 0))
=>
!(0 < 0 && 0 < 1) && !(0 < 0 && 1 < 0)
=>
!(false && true) && !(false && false)
=> !false && !false
=> true
```

So both nodes are considered equal and no insertion happens. The same holds for `Node<int, int>(1, 0)`.

The insertion of `Node<int, int>(1, 2)` works because

```
!(0 < 1 && 0 < 2) && !(1 < 0 && 2 < 0)
=>
!(true && true) && !(false && false)
=>
!true && !false
=>
false && true
=>
false
```

You can fix the problem by using another `operator<`, e.g., as said in the comments, by using `std::tie`.

Comment: Thanks, dtell. I got the solution how to fix it but just not understand. I believe you explain the root cause. Just curiously, why it natively determine equals by ```!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)``` instead of asking to implement operator '=='?

Comment: @user1256475 because `std::map` requires a [Strict Weak Ordering](https://www.boost.org/sgi/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).

Comment: @user1256475 `std::map` requires an `operator<` to meet the Complexity and Ordering requirements.  Given that `operator==` can be synthesized from `operator<` there is no need for `std::map` to require it or use it.  It also ensures that the equality test and the less-than test are testing the same data and will give the same results.